# MAVEN Archetype choosing

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

Hi i am just new to maven.
My requirement is to build a ear with 2 wars and also create a jar.
I tried using some archetypes but few folder structure are missing.
My maven folder structure should contain
src/main/
   java
   resource
   webapp
   test/java
   test/resource.
Which archetype will be a suitable?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have it in single project, Since the EAR consists of different modules.

So create separate project for war, jar and build.

To create war file use maven-archetype-webapp, and for jar use maven-archetype-quickstart.

Then include those project module in main project pom file with module

Eg

```
<modules>
    <module>expLogdao</module>
    <module>expLogservice</module>
    <module>expLogweb</module>
    <module>expLogear</module>
</modules>
```

Then use separate project to build ear

Now include all project modules in ear project dependencies tag

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.expLog.service</groupId>
        <artifactId>expLogservice</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.expLog.dao</groupId>
        <artifactId>expLogdao</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.expLog.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>expLogweb</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the formatting of the question it is a little tough to see what exactly you want.

Have you looked at **org.apache.maven.archetypes.maven-archetype-webapp**?