# How do add multiple projects resources to one project using Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have some 5 projects,A,B,C,D,E...
   and I want to generate a jar file out of project A and it has to include .class files from project B,C,D,E. all these projects are maven projects and I have compiled them and installed them on repository,and I have added dependencies of B,C,D,E projects in POM.xml of project A,when I run install on project A's pom.xml it is generating jar but it do not any classes so please guide how to include sources from other projects while generating the jar of project A

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look on
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211552/maven-archetype-choosing/10222292#10222292 .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Take a look at [some examples](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/index.html).